# jQuery run click function width a href id link ( www.mysite.com/#go1)

Tags: jquery, onclick, onload

I have a site width many click functions and I want to call click function if I send someone a deferent link to make my click function.

Exp.

If I send a link (www.mysite.com/#go1) run #go1 clck function

```
$( "#go1" ).click(function() {

   //something

}
```

If I send a link (www.mysite.com/#go2) run #go2 clck function

```
$( "#go2" ).click(function() {

   //something

}
```

The site is working fine but I cant share a link.
Thanks for any help (and sorry off my English :)

Comment: Try `$(window.location.href.split('/')[1]).trigger('click')` in your landing page

Comment: @Satpal wouldnt `$(window.location.hash).trigger('click')` be better?

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon, Yep absolutely. I missed that

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(location.hash).trigger('click')`